# Please help me combine the two codes for DHT11 and SW-420 Vibration sensor for arduino in one program

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch, temperature-sensor

The following is the code used for DHT11 Temperature and Humidity sensor:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3);
byte degree_symbol[8] = 
              {
                0b00111,
                0b00101,
                0b00111,
                0b00000,
                0b00000,
                0b00000,
                0b00000,
                0b00000
              };
int gate=11; 
volatile unsigned long duration=0;
unsigned char i[5];
unsigned int j[40];
unsigned char value=0;
unsigned answer=0;
int z=0;
int b=1;
void setup() 
{

lcd.begin(16, 2);
 lcd.print("Temp = ");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Humidity = ");
 lcd.createChar(1, degree_symbol);
 lcd.setCursor(9,0);
 lcd.write(1);
 lcd.print("C");
 lcd.setCursor(13,1);
 lcd.print("%");
}

void loop() 
{

 delay(1000);
 while(1)
 {
  delay(1000);
  pinMode(gate,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(gate,LOW);
  delay(20);
  digitalWrite(gate,HIGH);
  pinMode(gate,INPUT_PULLUP);//by default it will become high due to internal pull up
 // delayMicroseconds(40);


  duration=pulseIn(gate, LOW);
  if(duration <= 84 && duration >= 72)
  {
      while(1)
      {
        duration=pulseIn(gate, HIGH);

        if(duration <= 26 && duration >= 20){
        value=0;}

        else if(duration <= 74 && duration >= 65){
        value=1;}

        else if(z==40){
        break;}

        i[z/8]|=value<<(7- (z%8));
        j[z]=value;
        z++;
      }
    }
answer=i[0]+i[1]+i[2]+i[3];

if(answer==i[4] && answer!=0)
{
lcd.setCursor(7,0);
lcd.print(i[2]);
lcd.setCursor(11,1);
lcd.print(i[0]);
}

z=0;
i[0]=i[1]=i[2]=i[3]=i[4]=0;
 }
}
```

The following is the code for SW-420 Sensor:

```
int LED_Pin = 13;
int vibr_Pin =3;

void setup(){
  pinMode(LED_Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(vibr_Pin, INPUT); //set vibr_Pin input for measurment
  Serial.begin(9600); //init serial 9600
 // Serial.println("----------------------Vibration demo------------------------");
}
void loop(){
  long measurement =TP_init();
  delay(50);
 // Serial.print("measurment = ");
  Serial.println(measurement);
  if (measurement > 1000){
    digitalWrite(LED_Pin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(LED_Pin, LOW); 
  }
}

long TP_init(){
  delay(10);
  long measurement=pulseIn (vibr_Pin, HIGH);  //wait for the pin to get HIGH and returns measurement
  return measurement;
}
```

Assuming the DHT11 Pin configuration remains unchanged and you can change the pin configurations for SW-420 vibration sensor, please give me a combined code for the two sensors to display results in one program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arduino! Please take the [tour](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: Have you already tried combining those sketches? If yes, what's the problem you actually have? If no, try it. We are not supposed to do the job for you but we'll guide you to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple threads on how to combine two different sketches. One of the main things you have to do is refactor your code to get rid of calls to `delay()`. Do a Google search on `Arduino blink without delay` and read one of the tutorials you find. The idea is to make a call to the `millis()` function for each thing you want to do on a time intervl, save the current millis count, and then wait until the new value of millis() is greater than the saved value by your desired time interval. By doing that, your code does a very fast series of checks:

"is it time to do `<thing 1>` again?"

"Is it time to to `<thing 2>` again?"

"What about `<thing 3>`"

And repeats.

Then it doesn't freeze the rest of your sketch waiting for time to pass. (That is what `delay()` does. Everything stops until the delay time has passed, which is bad.)